# How can I create equidistant space between words based on their lengths?

Tags: html, css, web

Supposed I have a horizontal list:

About Admissions Academics Research News Events

I want them to be n-unit apart from the proceeding word based on their length.

---

### |  About | Admissions |  Academics |  Research | News | Events |

The illustration above is essentially the heart of my question. How can I make the words equidistant from each other? How can I vary the area of the rectangles in order to create equidistance?

For example, "Research" will have a much greater area than "News" but their distance is the same as the words such as "About" and "Admissions" and "Admissions" and "Academics".

```css
 .school_info {
      background-color: black;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .school_info_row {
      margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
      width: auto;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .public_info_container {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
    
    .public_info {
      font-size: 20;
      font-family:'Cinzel', serif;
      color: white;
      width: 150px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="school_info">
          <div class="row school_info_row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 public_info_container">
              <a class="public_info" href="">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 public_info_container">
              <a class="public_info" href="">Admissions</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 public_info_container">
              <a class="public_info" href="">Academics</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 public_info_container">
              <a class="public_info" href="">Research</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 public_info_container">
              <a class="public_info" href="">News</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 public_info_container">
              <a class="public_info" href="">Events</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. Bootstrap column totals must add up to 12. Your `col-lg-x` is correct, it adds up to 12, your `col-md-x` needs to have value `2` as well. Since both `lg` and `md` media-breakpoints use the value `2`, you can just replace it with `col-2`. I'm assuming this is bootstrap because those are bootstrap classes. Bootstrap also has `mx-auto` class so you can make the margins on the x-axis equidistant.

```css
.school_info {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}


.public_info {
  font-size: 20;
  font-family:'Cinzel', serif;
  color: white;
  /*width: 150px;*/  
}

.hilite {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="school_info">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 hilite">
          <a class="public_info mx-auto" href="">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 hilite">
          <a class="public_info mx-auto" href="">Admissions</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 hilite">
          <a class="public_info mx-auto" href="">Academics</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 hilite">
          <a class="public_info mx-auto" href="">Research</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 hilite">
          <a class="public_info mx-auto" href="">News</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 hilite">
          <a class="public_info mx-auto" href="">Events</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. From what I see when I run the snippet of code, it looks like "News" and "Events" are much further away from each other as opposed to "Admissions" and "Academics".

Is there a way in which I can make them closer so that the distance between "Admissions" and "Academics" is equal to "News" and "Events"? Since "News" and "Events" are much shorter words than "Admissions" and "Academics", the white space makes it look like they're much further away.

Comment: I modified the code so you can see it's exactly equal as you requested. That's just how it looks. Optical illusion. If you don't want this, then your original way of specifying the width would work. Just replace the class `row` with the flexbox classes `d-flex flex-row`  ---> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: Ah I see it now! Thank you! :)